# Docker copy file from host to image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have this image which my container is running lets call it image-test. Now I need to update it by copying a file inside one of its folders.
I created a DockerFile that have:

```
COPY Listener.jar /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/lib/Listener.jar.
```

Then I ran below command in cmd:

```
docker build -t image-1 -f copyFile.DockerFile . --no-cache
```

That built me a new image with the same name, however it is not in use by my container. Is there some other way I could UPDATE my existing image-1?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you should run your container again. `docker run -it --name new-container image-1`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use 'docker cp'.
See here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/

If you want to have a new image with the new file, then update your Dockerfile, rebuild the image and re-run the container with the new image.